# How I cant get de Properties in JSON Array Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift

My web services respond with this information

```
[
    {
        "IdWeek": 18340,
        "DateInit": "2018-08-19T00:00:00",
        "DateEnd": "2018-08-25T00:00:00",
        "TotalDays": 7,
        "WeekNumber": "34",
        "WeekDescription": "Semana del: 19/08/2018 al: 25/08/2018",
        "Status": 0,
        "IdWeekAccuredInit": 0,
        "IdWeekAccuredEnd": 0,
        "DateAccuredInit": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "DateAccuredEnd": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "IdWeek": 18330,
        "DateInit": "2018-08-12T00:00:00",
        "DateEnd": "2018-08-18T00:00:00",
        "TotalDays": 7,
        "WeekNumber": "33",
        "WeekDescription": "Semana del: 12/08/2018 al: 18/08/2018",
        "Status": 0,
        "IdWeekAccuredInit": 0,
        "IdWeekAccuredEnd": 0,
        "DateAccuredInit": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "DateAccuredEnd": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
```

I want to save these values in an object class called Week but my Task make an error.

```
class Week : Decodable
{
    let IdWeek:String
    let DateInit:Date
    let DateEnd:Date
    let TotalDays:Int
    let WeekNumber:String
    let WeekDescription:String
    let Status:Int
    let IdWeekAccuredInit:Int
    let IdWeekAccuredEnd:Int
    let DateAccuredInit:Date
    let DateAccuredEnd:Date
}

DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
    do
    {
        //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

        guard let weeks = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Week.self, from: data)
        else
        {
            print("Error: No puede decodificar en Weeks")
            return
        }

        for idWeek in weeks.IdWeek
        {
            print("idSemana:\(idWeek)")
        }

        print("Creando Objeto JSON")
        //print(json)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("El procesamiento del JSON tuvo un Error")
    }
})
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Comment: Your JSON is an array but you try to decode a single `Week`.

Comment: A few things after the good answers of @rmaddy: Please name your vars starting with a lowercase:  `WeekNumber` => `weekNumber`. To match the naming in the JSON, use `CodingKeys`. When you do a `catch`, please print the error, not a static message that is not indicating what is the error. Error can be different and it should give you hints about what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is an array, so you would need:

```
guard let weeks = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Week.self], from: data)
```

Also, don't capitalize your properties, the Swift convention is to use camel-case.